# Can a profinite completion be free pro-p?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

Is there a prime number $p$ and a finitely generated residually finite group whose profinite completion is a free pro-$p$ group on a nonempty finite set?

Thanks to YCor we see that we cannot take the group to be finitely generated.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179381/when-is-the-profinite-completion-a-pro-p-group

Comment: @YiftachBarnea I think I have seen it sometime ago. Does it answer my question?

Comment: The answer to the main question is trivially no, because if a f.g. group has abelianization $\mathbf{Z}^k\oplus F$ for $F$ finite, then the abelianization of its profinite completion is $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}^k\oplus F$. While the abelianization of a free pro-$p$-group of rank $\ell$ is $\mathbf{Z}_p^\ell$.

Comment: @YCor this is very simple, and I have missed this.

Comment: @YCor this even shows that if a profinite completion of f.g r.f group is pro-$p$ then its abelianization is finite?

Comment: If $G$ is the localization of $\mathbf{Z}$ at the prime $p$ (i.e. the subring of $\mathbf{Q}$ generated by all $\ell^{-1}$ for $\ell$ ranging over primes $\neq p$). Then its profinite completion is free pro-$p$ of rank 1.

Comment: Something similar can be done with higher rank: consider the smallest subgroup of the pro-$p$-completion $G$ of the free group $F_X$ containing $F_X$ and stable by extracting $\ell$-roots for all primes $\ell\neq p$. Then it's easy to see that its profinite completion is canonically $G$, hence free pro-$p$ on $X$.

Comment: @Pablo no it does not answer your questions. Your question was a specific case of my question. But unfortunately the negative answer to your question still leaves my question open.